# rmarkdown shiny user input in chunk?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have a shiny app that allows the user to download an HTML file (knitted from a .Rmd file) that includes the code used to run the analysis based on all the user inputs. I am trying to write the base .Rmd file that gets altered when user inputs vary. I am having trouble including user input variables (e.g. input$button1) into R code chunks. Say the user input for input$button1 = "text1".

```` ```{r} 
results <- someFun(input$button1)
``` ````

And I'd like to have it knitted like this:

```` ```{r} 
results <- someFun('text1')
``` ````

Every time I download the knitted HTML though, I get `input$button1` getting written to file. I would also like to be able to produce an .Rmd file that is formatted with this substitution. It seems like `knit_expand()` might be the key, but I can't seem to relate available examples to my specific problem. Is the proper way to `knit_expand()` the whole .Rmd file and specify explicitly all the parameters you want subbed in, or is there a more elegant way within the .Rmd file itself? I would prefer a method similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944715/conditionally-display-block-of-markdown-text-using-knitr), except that instead of using the `asis` engine, I could use the `r` one. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: the point, though, is to have it written to the HTML.

Comment: ```echo = FALSE``` hides the R code in the output, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Isnt that what you want? Try `echo=F, results='asis'`

Comment: no, I want to display the code, as in my example above. I'd like the user input to be displayed as whatever was input.

Comment: Please paste your entire R code chunk.

Comment: You need to pre-process the code chunk to resolve `input$button1` to its value. There are many ways to pre-process source documents, e.g. the `knit_expand()` function in **knitr**.

Comment: Thanks, Yihui. This allows me to generate a result with the proper text, but instead of the evaluation, I want that text to be within the code block in the knitted output. Is there some code chunk option in addition to echo=FALSE that will show the evaluated expression as a line of code in a block?

Comment: Yihui's past [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944715/conditionally-display-block-of-markdown-text-using-knitr) solved it. Modifying the `asis` definition like he recommends allows me to use `{asis, eval = x, echo = x}` to get the conditional behavior I want, while allowing me to input evaluated inline code. Thanks Yihui... just took me a while to find this.

Comment: Spoke too soon. Edited the above to rephrase the ongoing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. Solution below. Thanks to Yihui for the guidance. The trick was to `knit_expand()` the whole .Rmd file, then `writeLines()` to a new one, then render. With hindsight, the whole process makes sense. With hindsight.

For the example, `p1` is a character param `'ice cream'` and `p2` is an integer param `10`. There is a user-defined param in `ui.R` called `input$mdType` that is used to decide on the format provided for download.

Rmd file:

````
Some other text.
```{r}
results <- someFun("{{p1}}", {{p2}})
```
````

in the `downloadHandler()` within server.R:

```
  content = function(file) {
    src <- normalizePath('userReport.Rmd')
    # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
    # permission to the current working directory
    owd <- setwd(tempdir())
    on.exit(setwd(owd))
    file.copy(src, 'userReport.Rmd')
    exp <- knit_expand('userReport.Rmd', p1=input$p1, p2=input$p2)
    writeLines(exp, 'userReport2.Rmd')

    out <- rmarkdown::render('userReport2.Rmd', switch(input$mdType, 
             PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()))
    }
    file.rename(out, file)
  }
```

Resulting userReport2.Rmd before rendering:

````
```{r}
results <- someFun("ice cream", 10)
```
````