# How do I test a new knitr engine in R?

Tags: r, knitr

I forked knitr and am trying to add a new engine. Do I have to install my fork system-wide to see if it works with an RStudio notebook or can I run some R code directly to test the engine? I'd prefer not to overwrite the system knitr install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Yihui's response to

[Conditionally display block of markdown text using knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944715/conditionally-display-block-of-markdown-text-using-knitr)

He shows how to define a custom engine for an 'asis' chunk.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. It appears that you can add your own handler with knit_engines$set().