# RMarkdown Using comments to make sections optional

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is it possible to have entire sections programmatically commented out in RMarkdown. For example, say I have a section of my report :

````
### 2.1.   Heading

Blah blah blah my description, with `r variables` and other stuff.


#### Table 2.1.1. Sub heading

```{r table_2_1_1}

kable_2_1_1

```
````

Now based on a boolean in the code, I want to completely comment out that whole section. I've tried putting r variables into the report like "< !--" & "-->" but that does not work.

Comment: So, are you saying that if for example, you returned a 0 in the Section 1 block to a given variable, that you would want to ideally comment out this section 2?

Comment: This may be useful: [Conditionally display block of markdown text using knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944715/conditionally-display-block-of-markdown-text-using-knitr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a boolean value to `eval` in your rmd chunk to conditionally knit different blocks of rmarkdown code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Matt"
date: "12/21/2021"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

should_i_evaluate <- F
```

```{r header, eval = should_i_evaluate}
asis_output("# My Header")
```

```{asis, echo = should_i_evaluate}
 Blah blah blah my description, with `r names(mtcars[1:3])` and other stuff.
```

```{r cars, eval = should_i_evaluate}
summary(mtcars)
```
````

When `should_i_evaluate` is `TRUE`:

[image]

When `should_i_evaluate` is `FALSE`:

[image]

Comment: Nice. That's half way there. If there are further sections, is there a way to remove the text too. For example, the blah blah blah.

Comment: That's just the generic `yaml` that is part of my default settings - I'm sure yours would look different. At the very top of my answer, you can see `title: "Untitled"` and `author: "Matt"`. You'd just need to edit them to be `""` if you want it to be blank, or whatever other text you'd like.

Comment: Sorry, I realised that and quickly edited my comment.

Comment: No worries - I updated the solution where you would do nearly the same thing, but include the text in an `asis` block, and feed your boolean value to `echo` rather than `eval`

Comment: Any way to make this work for a heading?

Comment: Yes! Updated again - you need to include `library(knitr)` and add an `R` chunk using `asis_output()`

Comment: Yes! Works perfectly. Need to supply \n with the asis_output strings.